# testing the performance of a bunch of instructions in PHP

Tags: php, performance, time, benchmarking

I've finished to code a page that retrieves data from my database and then makes some manipulation on it. But wow, just when I thought I was coding slowly to prevent performance lack and to get the code beautified, I just end up with a page selfishly taking some big seconds to load.

However they are quite a lot of treatment and I want to optimize the lines. So the first thing I could do is to just read some articles on which methods to use rather than others to get the code faster but I'm pretty interested in finding a way to check time performance targeting a hand of instructions.

Typing things like 'benchmark a php program' leads me to some good pages of how to do so. However I'd like to ask here because I'm curious the way you do/the way you think it's better.

so let say i have the following pattern :

```
instruction 1;
...
instruction N;
```

from *instruction 1* to *N*, I want to check the time (or other types of information ?).

Answer (score 1):

One of the easier ways to measure your execution time and memory usage:

```
$start = microtime(true);

instruction 1;
...
instruction N;

echo 'Execution time: ' . ( microtime(true) - $start ) * 1000 . ' seconds <br />';
echo 'Memory usage: ' . memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024;
```

You can ofcourse place the echo rows between your instructions to measure the time from start of the script till the end of that instruction. This will provide insight which instruction takes the longest to complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = -microtime(TRUE);
//Execute your code here
$time += microtime(TRUE);
echo 'Execution time: '.$time.' seconds';
```

This code came from [*player27's* contribution to the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Comment: There are 1000 microseconds per second, so if, for example, you have 4000 microseconds, that is 4 seconds. To get that you have to divide 4000 by 1000.

Comment: but i think the function returns seconds already, cause it's unix timestamp with microseconds